# Solving this complicated integral using the Residue Theorem

Tags: integration, contour-integration

The following is an integral I am trying to evaluate

$$I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) \, ds = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{(1- \  \ 2 \pi j s  )^{m}}-1}{2\pi j s }\ e^{-2\pi j s \ \theta}\ ds $$

where $\theta$ is non-negative constant and $m$ is an positive integer.

Someone helped me by saying that, I can solve it exactly by closing the integration contour in the lower half complex plane, i.e using the Residue formula. Therefore I tried that below

**What I tried**

Using the  Residue Theorem ["Residue Theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)  and knowing that the pole is at $z^*=\frac{1}{2\pi j}$ then

$$I = -2 \pi j \ \ \text{Res}_{z^*= \frac{1}{2\pi j}}[f(z)]$$

Next I evaluate the residue ["residue of function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)), then

\begin{align}\text{Res}_{z^*= \frac{1}{2\pi j}}\left[f(z)\right]=&\lim_{z\rightarrow z^*} (z-z^*) \frac{\frac{1}{(1- \  \ 2 \pi j z  )^{m}}-1}{2\pi j z }\ e^{-2\pi j z\theta}\\ \\
&=\lim_{z\rightarrow z^*}\ (z-z^*) \frac{\frac{1}{(1- \frac {z}{z*}  )^{m}}-1}{2\pi j z }\ e^{-2\pi j z \theta}\\
&=\lim_{z\rightarrow z^*} (z-z^*) \frac{\frac{(z^*)^m}{(z^*-{z}  )^{m}}-1}{2\pi j z }\ e^{-2\pi j z\theta}\\
&=\lim_{z\rightarrow z^*}\frac{\frac{- (z^*)^m}{(z^*-{z}  )^{m-1}}-1}{2\pi j z }\ e^{-2\pi j z\theta}\\
\\ &= ????
\end{align}

I don't know if I am doing the right thing, do you think my derivation is correct?
Am I at least on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: You're using the formula for the residue at a simple pole, but you have a pole of order $m$. Write $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z - z^\ast)^m}$, where $$g(z) = (-1)^m\frac{1-(1-2\pi jz)^m}{(2\pi j)^m(2\pi j z)}e^{-2\pi j z\theta},$$ then the residue is $$\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^{m-1}\biggl\lvert_{z=z^\ast} g(z).$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I didn't understand your final formula do you mean this instead, $\frac{1}{(m-1)!}(\frac{d}{dz})^{m-1} g(z) \big|_{z=z^*}$?

Comment: @Henry You have to derive $m-1$ times.

Comment: No, you need to differentiate $m-1$ times, not just once (and if $m = 1$, you don't differentiate at all). Expand $g$ into its Taylor series about $z^\ast$, then you'll see that you need the coefficient of $(z-z^\ast)^{m-1}$.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher, thanks again, so if $m=2$, then i take the derivative of $g(z)$ twice let us call it $g{''}(z)$, then evaluate at $z=z^*$.

Comment: No, if $m = 2$, you differentiate once, $g'(z^\ast)$ is your residue. You differentiate twice for $m= 3$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yup thats true sorry, in the end I have to multiply by $2\pi j$ to get my final $I$, btw I know that $I$ should be real number, do you think in the end the answer using the Residue theorem will be give a real number?

Comment: It should, since the value is real. If you don't get a real result, you'll know that you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks. May I ask why is it that Residue theorem is able to solve this type of integration? Also do you think $z^*=\frac{1}{2 \pi j}$ that I have above is correct, ie is the pole correct?

Comment: Yes, the pole is correct, $1-2\pi jz = 0 \iff z = \frac{1}{2\pi j}$. Why: because holomorphic functions are very special, totally awesome.

Comment: @DanielFischer very cool, one last question, should I be multiplying the residue by $-2\pi j$ to get $I$ or  $+2\pi j$? Also do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept, you helped me alot. Thanks

Comment: $-2\pi j$, since the contour is traversed clockwise with the semicircle in the lower half-plane. I'll write an answer, will take a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the formula for the residue in the case of a simple pole, but here we have a pole of order $m$ (which may be $1$, but generally isn't), so the formula to use is

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z^\ast = \frac{1}{2\pi j}} [f(z)] = \lim_{z\to z^\ast} \frac{1}{(m-1)!}\biggl(\frac{d}{dz}\biggr)^{m-1} (z-z^\ast)^mf(z).\tag{1}$$

When we write $f$ in the form

$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z^\ast)^m},$$

a Taylor expansion of $g$ shows that

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(z^\ast)}{n!}\cdot (z-z^\ast)^{n-m},$$

and the residue is the coefficient of $(z-z^\ast)^{-1}$, so the term for $n = m-1$, which is

$$\frac{g^{(m-1)}(z^\ast)}{(m-1)!}.$$

Here, we have

$$f(z) = \frac{\frac{1}{(1-2\pi jz)^m}-1}{2\pi j z}e^{-2\pi jz\theta} = \frac{\frac{1-(1-2\pi jz)^m}{2\pi jz}}{(1-2\pi jz)^m}e^{-2\pi j z\theta} = \frac{(-1)^m\frac{1-(1-2\pi jz)^m}{(2\pi j)^m(2\pi jz)}e^{-2\pi jz\theta}}{\bigl(z-\frac{1}{2\pi j}\bigr)^m},$$

so

$$g(z) = (-1)^m\frac{1-(1-2\pi jz)^m}{(2\pi j)^m(2\pi jz)}e^{-2\pi jz\theta}.$$

Since $(1-2\pi jz)^m$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z^\ast = \frac{1}{2\pi j}$, that part of $g$ doesn't contribute to the residue, and we only need to compute the derivatives of

$$\frac{1}{2\pi jz} e^{-2\pi j z\theta}$$

and multiply with the constant factors, which makes the computation a bit simpler.

Comment: Does this method work if $m$ is not an integer?

Comment: No, if $m$ is not an integer, then your integrand doesn't have a pole at $z^\ast$ but a branch-point, and you must have a branch-cut from $z^\ast$ to $\infty$. Sometimes, one can use branch-cuts and the residue theorem to compute integrals (things like $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx$), but I don't see a way to do that here for non-integer $m$.

Comment: if you don't mind me commenting again on this, i was wondering why isnt the pole at zero considered in the analysis? thanks

Comment: Here we don't have a pole at $0$, the zero of the denominator $2\pi js$ is cancelled by the zero of the numerator $\frac{1}{(1-2\pi js)^m}-1$ at $0$, so the integrand is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ [after removing the removable singularity at $0$].

Comment: is this the same case as the integrand i mentioned in this question I asked here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142633/using-the-residue-theorem-to-solve-this-integral Reason I am asking is because I get comments that zero is also a pole...@Daniel Fischer

Comment: Basically the same, @Henry. The numerator over there has a slightly more complicated form, but it also has a zero at $0$ [just insert $s = 0$ and your numerator becomes $\frac{1}{1^3\cdot 1^3}-1 = 1-1 = 0$], so the zero of the denominator is again cancelled.

Comment: does that mean that the solution of that answer should be very similar to this one here...

Comment: Depends on what you call "very". That you have two different factors $(1-2\pi ja_kz)^3$ there makes it more complicated to do the calculations. But the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel have I approached it correctly in my attempt?

Comment: @DanielFischer One question regarding your answer above why is the residue the coefficient of $(z-z^{\ast})^{-1}$?

Comment: @Tyrone Sometimes that's the "working definition" of the residue. If you're working with the definition via the integral, note that all other terms in the Laurent expansion of $f$ in $0<\lvert z-z^\ast\rvert<\rho$ (where $\rho$ is chosen small enough that $f$ has no other singularity in the disk $D_\rho(z^\ast)$ than $z^\ast$) have a primitive in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z^\ast\}$, so the integral of those over a closed curve is $0$. That leaves $$\int_{\lvert z-z^\ast\rvert=\rho/2} f(z)\,dz=\int_{\lvert z-z^\ast\rvert=\rho/2} a_{-1}(z-z^\ast)^{-1}\,dz = 2\pi i a_{-1}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer isnt it sufficient to just say that $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z^\ast)^m},$ and from there evaluate the residue without really doing the expansion of $g(z)$?

Comment: @Tyrone The question is _how_ you can evaluate the residue. Computing the expansion of $g$ to the required order is often the easiest or even the only feasible way. But when you have other ways to determine the residue, you can do it differently. There's usually more than one correct way to obtain a result. But some ways are easier than others. Which is the easiest depends.