# Using the Residue theorem or Fourier transform to solve this integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The following is an integral I am trying to evaluate

$$I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) \, ds = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{(1- \  \ 2 \pi j a_1 s  )^{3}(1-2\pi j a_2 s)^3}-1}{2\pi j s }\ e^{-2\pi j s \ \theta}\ ds $$

where $\theta$ is non-negative constant and $a_1,a_2$ are positive integers.

Using the  Residue Theorem and knowing that the pole is at $z_1^*=\frac{1}{2\pi ja_1}$ and at $z_2^*=\frac{1}{2\pi ja_2}$  then

$$I = -2 \pi j \ \ \text{Res}_{z_1^*= \frac{1}{2\pi ja_1},z_2^*=\frac{1}{2\pi j a_2}}[f(z)]$$

Comment: What is your motivation for evaluating this integral?

Comment: @Assaultous2 do you mean why did I end up solving it :)?

Comment: yea, or at least trying to solve it

Comment: So in my research I am looking to evaluate probability of an expression that involves several random variables, it turned out to be that I have to find the Laplace transform, the random variables are Gamma distributed and so I get the integration above. I know this isnt very clear, but I think it might give an idea why I ended up with it

Comment: It appears that you also have a pole on your contour,  at z=0,  which is a bit of a problem for this method, no?

Comment: Thanks Alan,Why do I have a pole on z=0? @Alan

Comment: @henry Unless I'm misreading it, the $2\pi js$ term in the denominator

Comment: I see yes, I have asked a very similar question in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072483/solving-this-complicated-integral-using-the-residue-theorem but I cant seem to leverage the result to this question...

Comment: now i am wondering... in the link i provided before i asked a similar question please check my comment before.. i got an answer which i accepted .. but the answer didnt treated the pole at 0...do you thibk the answer is wrong?

Comment: @Assaultous2 The zero of the denominator at $0$ is cancelled by a zero of the numerator at $0$, hence $0$ is a removable singularity of the integrand.

Comment: @Alan See above comment.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks Daniel

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahh right, thanks.   Doing singularity analysis now in analytic combinatorics, still getting used to it

Comment: Are you looking for asymptotics ? or exact formula ? The standard procedure is to substitute $s= 1/a_1 + z$, and Taylor expand the function, retaining only the coefficient of $1/z$. This is usually best done using a computer algebra system. You shouldn't expect a very nice formula in the end, as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is solved below with a different method (in case $a_1\neq a_2$), involving Fourier transform :

[image]

In the case $a_1=a_2$, a similar calculus but much simpler, can be done with the same method:

[image]

SOLVING WITH THE COMPLEX RESIDUES METHOD :

Computing the residue relative to the pole $z=z_1$, requires to compute the second derivative of a function of the form :
$$f(z)=C\left(\frac{1}{(z-z_2)^3}-\frac{(z-z_1)^3}{(z_1 z_2)^3}\right)\frac{e^{-p\,z}}{z}$$
with $\:z_1=\frac{1}{2\pi i a_1}\:$ ; $\:z_2=\frac{1}{2\pi i a_2}\:$ ; $\: p=2\pi i \theta\:$ ; $\:C=\frac{1}{(2\pi i a_1)^3(2\pi i a_2)^3 2\pi i}\:$
and similary for the pole $z=z_2$

This leads to very big equations which should be arduous to carry out by hand. I did it with the help of a symbolic sofware. The residues obtained for the poles $z_1$ and $z_2$ (of course not for $z=0$ which is a removable singular point) finally lead to the same formula already given above.

Comment: The above images should be TeXed properly, since if their server goes down, your answer will be rendered uselss.

Comment: Yes, I know and I am sorry for that. But I have not sufficient available time to translate them on latex form. So, my choice is to post them as they are, or to not answer to the question.

Comment: If you're TeXing that using software similar to MathType, there is usually an option to copy what you've written in TeX code (as opposed to copying it as an image). You can paste the code here and it should work.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff : What FREE software which can edit Latex (and of similar use than MathType)  do you recommend ?

Comment: Emacs in opinion is the way to go but check out [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) thread on Latex SE

Comment: @JJacquelin I have one question regarding this answer you  provided when you did the partial fraction expansion, did you account for the $\frac{1}{z}$, because it seems like that partial fraction you did accounts only for $\frac{1}{(1-a_1z)^3}\frac{1}{(1-a_2z)^3}$ only am I right?

Comment: @JJacquelin, if you believe that it is correct please let me know

Comment: The partial fraction expansion is not for $\frac{1}{(1-a_1z)^3}\frac{1}{(1-a_2z)^3}$ but for $\left(\frac{1}{(1-a_1z)^3}\frac{1}{(1-a_2z)^3}-1\right)\frac{1}{z}$. First, you have to write it with a common denominator. If you do that, you see a simplification which leads to the common denominator = $(1-a_1z)^3(1-a_2z)^3$ The common denominator is not $(1-a_1z)^3(1-a_2z)^3z$. The $z$ disapears thanks to the simplification. There is no pole $z=0$ : that is why it is called a "removable singularity".

Comment: awesome, I have one more question, I would like to take the answer for this integral, which you provided here, multiply it by a function $f(a_1,a_2)$ and then perform a double integral over that for some values of  $0<a_1< a_2<\infty$ do you think it is possible? because I tried to do that in matlab and I failed, i think the reason why is becaue the answer provided here has at the denominator $a_1,a_2$ @JJacquelin

Comment: Yes it is possible. But take care to the first two terms $\frac{A_1}{1-a_1z}$ and $\frac{B_1}{1-a_2z}$. The integration of each one taken individually will failed because the antiderivatives are logarithms, not convergent at infinity. The two terms have to be sumed together before integration, in order to have a second order polynomial as common denominator.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I would like to take the answer you provided up that looks like $f_1(a_2,a_2) xp(-\theta/a_1)+ f_2(a_1,a_2)exp(-\theta/a_2)$ multiply it by some new function $g(a_1,a_2)$ and then double integrate it, MATLAB seems to give me that this cant be performed numerically...@JJacquelin

Comment: Well, it is not prohibited to multiply by $f(a_1,a_2)$ and perform a double integral. But one cannot say a-priori if the integral will be convergent or not. It depends on the function $f(a_1,a_2)$ and on the boundaries of the integrals.

Comment: sure thanks i understand what you mean @JJacquelin